# Connect with adb to device via network

Tags: adb, networking, customization

I want to do some android theming, but I have a question on what the best way is to set up the system.

I have 2 computers here at home. So i was thinking of having the following setup if that is possible.

One one computer I want to set up the whole android SDK plus eclipse and run a device in an emulator. And on the other I want to set everything up so I can push and pull from the other pc. The pc's are connected via ethernet.

Is this type of setup even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  On your second PC, set the environment variable `ADBHOST` to the IP address of the first PC and run the adb server and client.  Related steps (more detailed) are [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-on-freerunner/wiki/AndroidDebugBridge).

Although you're not connecting to a physical device, it is apparently also possible to do so over the network without using USB.  Instructions for that are [here](http://web.me.com/elvis.dowson/Technote/Android_Technotes/Entries/2010/11/27_How_to_setup_adb_over_ethernet_for_debugging_android_applications_using_the_Gumstix_Chestnut43_expansion_board.html).

Comment: +1 Sounds great! I'm going to check out the links, and read in a little bit. Ill except when its all set up. Thanks for helping me so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the reason for the 2nd PC.  You can push and pull from/to multiple android devices (emulators and physical handsets/tablets) connected to one machine via adb.

Command "adb devices" will return all of the connected physical devices as well as emulated ones, e.g.:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
HT035P90XXXXX    device
```

Where "emulator-5554" is the emulator, and the other is a physical handset.

From there on you can target a specific device with adb's "-s [serial_no]" switch.

For example:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell
```

or

```
adb -s HT035P90XXXXX pull /system/app/Music.apk c:\
```

or any other adb command.

Comment: That emulator lags up my whole pc, it's easier for me to just have it on a separate system.